# How to apply tags to Elastic Beanstalk Application Load Balancer?

Tags: terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I need to apply tags to Elastic Beanstalk Internet facing Application Load Balancers. I do not want to apply the tags to the Elastic Beanstalk Environment.

My terraform script can apply settings to the Application Load Balancer using this pattern, this **WORKS**:

```
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.is_application_load_balancer ? ["include"] : []
    content {
      name      = "AccessLogsS3Enabled"
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
      value     = var.access_log_enabled
      resource  = ""
    }
  }

  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.is_application_load_balancer ? ["include"] : []
    content {
      name      = "Protocol"
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      value     = "HTTPS"
      resource  = ""
    }
  }
```

However, I cannot apply tags using the same pattern. This does **NOT** work:

```
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.is_application_load_balancer ? ["include"] : []
    content {
      name      = "Tags"
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
      value     = module.meta.waf_tags
      resource  = ""
    }
  }
```

The error:

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on ../../../modules/elastic-beanstalk-env/eb-app.tf line 272, in resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalk_environment":
│  272:       value     = module.meta.waf_tags
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.meta.waf_tags is object with 8 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
```

module.meta.waf_tags:

```
output "waf_tags" {
  value = {
    Owner       = "Owner"
    Product     = "Product"
    Service     = "Service"
    Team        = "Team"
    Terraform   = replace(abspath(path.root),"/.*/*terraform/","terraform")
    WAF_Enabled = "True"
    WAF_Mode    = "Block"
    WAF_Policy  = "Log4j"
  }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to apply the tags using terraform?

Thank you

Comment: " does NOT work:" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: Also where is the rst of your code? What are `var.is_application_load_balancer`, `module.meta.waf_tags`? Where does `dynamic "setting"` come from?

Comment: Wow, sorry published before adding all the detail.
`var.is_application_load_balancer` is TRUE when script is executed.

`dynamic "setting"` blocks are used in the resource block: `resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalk_environment"` script.

`module.meta.waf_tags` was added to the question.

Comment: Where did you find that `aws:elbv2:loadbalancer` namespace supports `Tags`? Its centerly not in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbv2).

Comment: <Awesome. The "Tags" block was recommended by another resource. I had assumed it was supported but checking the doc confirms it is not.

Comment: Also, Terraform can be configured to use default tags, meaning that it will tag anything it possibly can: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging#propagating-tags-to-all-resources